# copy filter data to same worksheet using vba

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

i need true values from column K under column O

By any chance is it possible to copy filtered data in the same worksheet through VBA ? Can anyone confirm what is the error in the below code i am trying to copy filter data in cell O3 till last row.

```
Sub filterdata()

Dim cv As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Dim elr As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set cv = Worksheets("Coverage")

Sheets("Coverage").Select
cv.Range("O3:T3", Range("O3").End(xlDown)).clear

lr = cv.Cells(Rows.count, 11).End(xlUp).Row

If cv.FilterMode Then cv.ShowAllData

With cv.Rows(1)

 Range("L2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="TRUE"
 If cv.Range("K2:K" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.count > 1 Then
    cv.Range("K3" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=cv.Range("O3")


    End If
        .AutoFilter Field:=2

  End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: I am getting Run time error '1004' - This information cannot be pasted because the copy area and the paste area are not the same size and shape. The issue is with the below code    
cv.Range("K3" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=cv.Range("O3")

Comment: i basically need all the true values from column K for eg. DMP.AX, ALD.AX etc under column "O3"

Comment: column L values need not copy to column O, these are just to filter

Comment: i think i found the issue , fixed it here is the correct line of code.
cv.Range("K3:K" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=cv.Range("O3")